# C# string encoding using ToBase64String

Tags: c#, java, encryption

I'm working on a C# encryption program, and I am pretty much done with it.

It encrypts and decrypts a string that I pass as an argument.

The only problem is that when I compare to equivalent Java encryption program I notice that c# converts hexadecimal of special characters.

Is there a way I can tell the program not to convert special characters and just represent them as hexadecimal?

Here is an example

Java :

```
4g8LAQXy%2B1M%3D
```

C#:

```
4g8LAQXy+1M=
```

As you can see, `'+'` in hex is `2B` and `'='` in hex is `3D`.

Comment: I hope you aren't using Base64 as an encryption scheme

Comment: % should not appear in  Base64 output, the Java result looks URL encoded? where does it come from?

Comment: To tag onto @DGibbs, Base64 is not encryption - it is encoding.  Base64 is no better than plaintext.  Just want to make sure that was clear.

Comment: I'm emulating PBEwith md5 and des c#. sorry i wasn't clear in the op

Comment: I have changed the title of the question to ensure base64 is **not** being confused with encryption.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure how to title this question without confusing everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like url % encoding, not base-64; have you tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` ?

```
string s = "4g8LAQXy+1M=";
string t = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s); // 4g8LAQXy%2b1M%3d
```

Comment: @user that method goes all the way back to 2.0 - just add a reference to System.Web.dll; or alternatively just write it yourself - it is pretty trivial to do (we use a custom one, IIRC)

Comment: Is there a way for the %2b to be %2B? same for the %3d

Comment: @user well, in url-encode terms they are identical. You could hand-roll the encode, though - it is mainly "check the whitelist, check if it is outside the ascii range; if so, utf-8 encode and hex encode that

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I approached it a little differently. I just looked for the % and just uppercased the following two characters. It worked as I intended.